# How to use Alarm Manager Content Provider.

Tags: android

When i use Alarma Manager. showing Permission Error. kindly tell me, which permission we have to use in manifest file.

i m using this code...

```
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.deskclock/alarm");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) 
            {
          String names[] = c.getColumnNames();
           for (String temp : names) {
            System.out.println(temp);

            }

           if (c.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                  int i = 0;
                  for (int j = 0; j < c.getColumnCount(); j++) 
                      {
                          c.getString(j));
                   }
                 } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the LogCat output for the error. You will see there exactly the missing permission. If you can't figure it out paste the output here.

Comment: 05-02 05:51:48.271: W/ActivityManager(2409): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10029


05-02 05:51:48.271: W/ActivityManager(2409): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10029



05-02 05:51:48.271: W/ActivityManager(2409): Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.deskclock.AlarmProvider from ProcessRecord{2b1b8ed0 17304:Package Name/10050} (pid=17304, uid=10050) requires null or null
i am getting this error...